# Long start time for idl

Tags: idl-programming-language

IDL (v8.6) takes a long time to start (minutes) even for plain start (`idl -IDL_STARTUP ""`). It quickly prints

```
IDL 8.6.1 (linux x86_64 m64).
(c) 2017, Exelis Visual Information Solutions, Inc., a subsidiary of Harris Corporation.
```

and then it seems to hang. When the license is finally allocated (with flexera), it's ready. (Licenses are available; trial mode is not entered.)

Also to exitting idl take many seconds/minutes for simple <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>).

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Seems for autodesk there was a similar problem withhttps://forums.autodesk.com/t5/installation-licensing/license-manager-response-is-slow/td-p/8412093 and it was solved.

Answer (score 1):

We've observed that obtaining a license over the network was one of the causes that we could control when it came to slow startup times.
This was a problem noticed [post-version 8.5](https://groups.google.com/g/idl-pvwave/c/gXyysZM-6TQ/m/3CRdYeM3BAAJ).
You could try a local license.